# Change my device minimum width from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android 7.1 device, and I need something to change my "minimum width". I change that through "Developer mode" options, there I can change that.
The point is that I want to create an app that does that without going every time to options menu, and I just press on a widget and it changed. I want to know if there is any API or function to access and change that option directly from Android Studio....

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that Android Studio is able to interact with device developer options.

But if you need is to test screen layouts with different device screen widths, Android Studio let you visualize screen layout rendering preview ("design" bottom tab of layout editor) and choose different device configurations (device combobox in top of editor) with different min-widths configuration. You can also create your custom configuration.